# logic app connection to storage account failing

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep, azure-logic-app-standard

I have created logic app storage connection using below code but unfortunately it is throwing error.

```
resource blobConnector 'Microsoft.Web/connections@2018-07-01-preview' = {
  name: 'apic-d365-azureblob12345'
  location: Location
  kind: 'V2'
  properties: {
    alternativeParameterValues: {}
    api: {
      id: 'subscriptions/${subscription().subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/${Location}/managedApis/azureblob'
    }
    customParameterValues: {}
    displayName: 'azureblob'
    parameterValueSet: {
      name: 'managedIdentityAuth'
      values: {}
    }
  }
}
```

Role assignment:

```
resource blobcontributorroleassignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-10-01-preview' = {
  name: guid(resourceGroup().id, logicappsite.id, blobcontributorroledefination.id)
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: blobcontributorroledefination.id
    principalType: 'ServicePrincipal'
    principalId: logicappsite.identity.principalId
  }
}
```

below is the error it is throwing while making connection

**"error": "'Operation not supported with AAD authentication, use Azure Storage Account name/key connection instead**

Could someone help me if I am missing something or doing wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to create an access policy to allow the logic app to access the connection api:

```bicep
// Grant permission to the logic app standard to access the connection api
resource blobConnectorAccessPolicy 'Microsoft.Web/connections/accessPolicies@2018-07-01-preview' = {
  name: logicappsite.name
  parent: blobConnector
  location: location
  properties: {
    principal: {
      type: 'ActiveDirectory'
      identity: {
        tenantId: subscription().tenantId
        objectId: logicappsite.identity.principalId
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes , i have this access policy added as well. but still its throwing error

Comment: Could you share the action you are using in your workflow ?

Comment: "actions": {"Uploads_a_Blob_to_Azure_Storage": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "parameters": {
                                "blobName": "@concat(body('Parse_response_from_D365_integration_workflow')?['status'],workflow()['run']['name'],'.xml')",
                                "containerName": "coantainer1",
                                "content": "@body('Reads_Blob_Content_from_Azure_Storage')?['content']"},   "serviceProviderConfiguration": {
                                "connectionName": "AzureBlob",

Comment: Weird, I have it working. When you select the action, you need to choose Azure not buit-in action.

Comment: its working for finally

Comment: Hello, I am facing a similar issue but I do not know where the policy must be added, is that at connection level? or is this a policy that belongs to the Logic App? thanks in advance!

Comment: at the connection level. In the sample, the parent is the `blobConnector`.